# How do i store info in my float and make it re-usable?

Tags: java

So basically, i need to make a vending machine and I need to make a float or a variable at least.

It needs to remember the amount I put in and use it later.

Right now I think I'm making a new wallet every time I start the code or when it repeats itself.
I'm really new to programming and I hit a brick wall.

Sorry if the code is messy :/ :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean runmachine = true;
        while (runmachine)
        {
        System.out.println("\n" +
                "Hi, welcome to vending machine #203. What would you like today? A drink?");
        System.out.println("Options: yes and no");



        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String drink = scan.nextLine();
        if (drink.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Would you like your drink cold or hot?");
            String cold_drink = scan.nextLine();

            if (cold_drink.equals("hot")) {
                System.out.println("Options: 1 = Coffee (black), 2 = Tea (green) 3 = Warm water");
            }
            String warm_drinks = scan.nextLine();
            if (warm_drinks.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 1.99 - Type PAYH1 to pay");

            }
            String PAYH1 = scan.nextLine();
            if (PAYH1.equals("PAYH1"))
            {
                System.out.println("please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (in Euro's - accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                float deposit = s.nextInt();
                float price;
                    price  = (float) 1.99;
                float wallet = deposit - price;
                if (wallet < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                    System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                }


            }

            if (warm_drinks.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 1.49 - Type PAYH2 to pay");
            }
            String PAYH2 = scan.nextLine();
            if (PAYH2.equals("PAYH2"))
            {
                System.out.println("please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (in Euro's - accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                float deposit = s.nextInt();
                float price;
                price  = (float) 1.49;
                float wallet = deposit - price;
                if (wallet < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                    System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                }

            }

            if (warm_drinks.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 0.40 - Type PAYH3 to pay");
            }
            String PAYH3 = scan.nextLine();
            if (PAYH3.equals("PAYH3"))
            {
                System.out.println("please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (in Euro's - accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                float deposit = s.nextInt();
                float price;
                price  = (float) 0.40;
                float wallet = deposit - price;
                if (wallet < 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                    System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                }

            }


            if (cold_drink.equals("cold"))
            {
                System.out.println("Options: 1 = fanta, 2 = Cola, 3 = Ice Tea");
            }

            String cold_drinks = scan.nextLine();
            if (cold_drinks.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 1.99 - Type PAYC1 to pay");
                String PAYC1 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYC1.equals("PAYC1"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (in Euro's - accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 1.99;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}

                }
            if (cold_drinks.equals("2"))
            {
                System.out.println("That will be 1.49 - Type PAYC2 to pay");
                String PAYC2 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYC2.equals("PAYC2"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (in Euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 1.49;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }
            if (cold_drinks.equals("3"))
            {
                System.out.println("That will be 0.40 - Type PAYC3 to pay");
                String PAYC3 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYC3.equals("PAYC3"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. (In Euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 1.49;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }
        }
        if (drink.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("A meal it is! Would you like it to have meat in it?");
            String vegetarian = scan.nextLine();

            if (vegetarian.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("Options: 1 = Salad, 2 = Vegetarian pasta 3 = Rice with eggs and vegetables");
            }
            if (vegetarian.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 4.99 - Type PAYV1 to pay");
                String PAYV1 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYV1.equals("PAYV1"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (In Euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 4.99;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }
            if (vegetarian.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 2.49 - Type PAYV2 to pay");
                String PAYV2 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYV2.equals("PAYV2"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (in Euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 2.49;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }
            if (vegetarian.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 5.29 - Type PAYV3 to pay");
                String PAYV3 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYV3.equals("PAYV3"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (In Euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 5.29;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }

            if (vegetarian.equals("yes")) {
                System.out.println("Options: 1 = Salad, 2 = Chicken strips 3 = Burgor");

            }
            String meat = scan.nextLine();
            if (meat.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 4.99 - Type PAYM1 to pay");
                String PAYM1 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYM1.equals("PAYM1"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (In euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 4.99;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}

            }
            if (meat.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 2.49 - Type PAYM2 to pay");
                String PAYM2 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYM2.equals("PAYM2"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (In Euro's - accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 2.49;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }
            if (meat.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("That will be 5.29 - Type PAYM3 to pay");
                String PAYM3 = scan.nextLine();
                if (PAYM3.equals("PAYM3"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter amount amout of money you wish to desposit, type 0 if not necessary. -- (In euro's - Accepted coins: 1 euro, 2 euro, 5 euro bill and 10 euro bill)");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    float deposit = s.nextInt();
                    float price;
                    price  = (float) 5.29;
                    float wallet = deposit - price;
                    if (wallet < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not enough money!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for visiting!");
                        System.out.println("You have " + wallet + " euro in exchange.");
                    }}
            }



        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. Do you want to save the wallet event when restarting the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but you're declaring your variables every time you use them.

If you want to use your `wallet` variable throughout the scope of your program, you only need to declare it once, and then reassign it for new values.

```
float wallet = 0;
//code...//
wallet = deposit - price;
```

If you declare a new variable in every `if` statement, even if it has the same name (e.g. wallet), then it will not be used when it goes out of scope.

You should declare the variables you're using outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: So do i need to put my float wallet = 0; above the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes. You can declare it where you declared runmachine.

Comment: So i'm using intelliJ and it says it's not allowed there and that the float money; is never used.                                                                                     boolean runmachine = true;
        while (runmachine)
            float wallet;
        {
            System.out.println("\n" +
                    "Hi, welcome to vending machine #203. What would you like today? A drink?");
            System.out.println("Options: yes and no");

Comment: Find the line: boolean runmachine = true; Then on the line above it, type: float wallet = 0;

Comment: Yes, you need to extract the definition of your **wallet** variable outside the loop. ANyway, you definitively should create some independant methods allowing to improve legibility of your source code (for instance, one method to read the user's input, another to compute/update the wallet ...).

Comment: Expounding on what Bsquare said: When you see lots of duplicate code, you should think about how you could only write the code once, and have it used multiple times by making it into a method that you can call.

Comment: Hmmmm, okay. It seems to have worked for 50%, the only probem i now have is that all the "float wallet = deposit - price;" parts now have a red alert saying Variable wallet is already defined in the scope.

Comment: Once you declare the type of the variable (e.g. float), then you don't have to put that in front of your variable every time you use it. So delete float and just use wallet. "wallet = deposit - price;"

Comment: Also, consider looking up how to debug. It's a must have skill if you want to program. Good luck!